# ¿Como hacer que un iframe sea redimensionable?

Tags: html, css, html5

En un sistema, utilizaba un `<textarea>` para mostrar los mensajes que se enviaban entre usuarios del mismo y por defecto los `<textarea>` se pueden redimensionar desde la esquina inferior derecha.

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Luego actualice el sistema, los mensajes dejaron de ser texto plano y pasaron a ser `HTML`, por lo que reemplace los `<textarea>` por `<iframe sandbox="">` para proteger el sistema de posible ataques de [`inyección HTML`](https://www.hackingarticles.in/beginner-guide-html-injection/), etc.

En resumen, la pregunta es: ¿Es posible hacer que un `<iframe>` pueda redimensionarse al igual que los `<textarea>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pude replicar el mismo comportamiento de los `<textarea>` usando `CSS` y estableciendo [`resize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/resize) igual a `both`

#### Ejemplo

```css
iframe {
  resize: both;
}
```

```html
<iframe></iframe>
```